# joining 2 tables in sql which has no dependency on each other

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have 2 tables in the following way

Table 1:

```
e_id  e_name  e_salary  e_age  e_gender  e_dept
---------------------------------------------------
1     sam     95000     45     male      operations
2     bob     80000     21     male      support
3     ann     125000    25     female    analyst
```

Table 2:

```
d_salary  d_age  d_gender  e_dept
----------------------------------
 34000     25     male      Admin
 56000     41     female    Tech
 77000     35     female    HR
```

I want the output something like this:

```
e_id  e_name  e_salary  e_age  e_gender  e_dept      d_salary  d_age  d_gender  e_dept
1     sam     95000     45     male      operations  34000     25     male      Admin
2     bob     80000     21     male      support     56000     41     female    Tech
3     ann     125000    25     female    analysts    77000     35     female    HR
```

There is no dependency between the tables. No common columns. No primary or foreign key.
I tried using cross join that results in duplicate rows because it works on M X N

I am new to this SQL thing. Can someone help me, please? Thanks in advance

Comment: Does the expected result make any sense? I can't see why you would like to do this. What's the purpose of Table2?

Comment: Why you doing this? A row isn't a row if there is no relation between cells.

Comment: Do you have any order on the second table. So how do you know that `Admin` needs to be joined on `e_id = 1`

Comment: @jarlh, It's weird I know. But this is what I have to do. This is just a dummy explanation of the work that I have to do. I have to add 2 separate tables with no dependency to form a new table that has both tables columns and its data. And I also don't know whether its doable or not. That's why asking other people opinion

Comment: @S-Man, Please don't mind the data. It's just random data. My main purpose is to join 2 different tables in the above way. But those 2 tables have no dependency or relation between them.

Answer (score 0):

Though I didn't get the reason behind your desired output but you can get that with below query:

```
select a.e_id  ,a.e_name  ,a.e_salary  ,a.e_age  ,a.e_gender  ,a.e_dept,b.d_salary  ,b.d_age  ,b.d_gender  ,b.e_dept
from 
(select e_id  ,e_name  ,e_salary  ,e_age  ,e_gender  ,e_dept, row_number()over(order by e_id)rn
from table1)a
inner join 
(select d_salary  d_age  d_gender  e_dept,row_number()over(order by d_salary) rn
from table 2) b
on a.rn=b.rn
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can create a row count using the [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) on both tables and use this as join criterion. But this requires a certain order for both tables, which means that you have explicitly tell the query why is the `Admin` record ordered first and must be joined on the first record of table 1:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *,
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY e_id) as row_count -- assuming e_id is your order criterion
    FROM table1
) t1
JOIN (
    SELECT
        *,
        row_number() OVER (ORDER BY /*whatever you expect to be ordered*/) as row_count
    FROM table2
) t2
ON t1.row_count = t2.row_count
```